# Backup Compressed and Fixed filename

Tags: sql-server

I have a backup application and some of my customers want their SQL Server databases backed up. I need SQL Server to give me compressed files with file fixed name (without timestamp). I have tried using the command 'SqlCmd -E -S...' but it does not compress the database (need to change configuration in SQL Server) which customers are not comfortable with. Also due to lack of free space on the hard disk we need it compressed. With 'SQL Enterprise Studio' the backup that takes place always has a timestamp in the name. I need the backup filename fixed eg: ABC.BAK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you necessarily have to use this backup application you mentioned? I'd just whip the T-SQL at it:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [CustomerDB] TO DISK = N'D:\ABC.BAK' WITH COMPRESSION
GO;
```

That'll let you define the file names as well as override the server's default compression for that backup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sqlcmd to both compress the backup and give the backup file whatever name you want. sqlcmd can take an input file to execute against a SQL Server. Here is an example of the sqlcmd you would run

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i ./SQLQuery1.sql
```

Where I'm connecting to my localhost installation of SQL Server (default instance name), and a trusted connection. You know this bit already of course. The new thing is the command-line option at the end.

```
-i ./SQLQuery1.sql
```

Here is an example SQLQuery1.sql file (you can of course call it whatever you would like)

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Example.bak';

BACKUP DATABASE [Example] TO DISK = @Path
WITH NAME = N'Example-Full Database Backup'
    ,COMPRESSION;
GO
```

Change the @Path variable to wherever you want the backup to be written and change the name of the file at the end of the @Path variable to whatever you want to call the file.